# Reading .so files from android process memory

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native, android-memory

I am trying to read all the .so files from the android process memory and store it in a map for later usage. Though, the below code snippet works for all non rooted android devices, it is not working for rooted android 7 device, Nexus 6.
The "m_modules" map is always empty. But, when I run "cat /proc/self/maps" in the adb shell, it is showing the memory mapping with the .so files.
Can someone kindly help me out.

Native code snippet used in Android :

```
bool elf_hooker::phrase_proc_maps()
{

    m_modules.clear();
    FILE* fd = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    if (fd != NULL) {
    char buff[2048+1];
    while(fgets(buff, 2048, fd) != NULL) {
        const char *sep = "\t \r\n";
        char *line = NULL;
        char* addr = strtok_r(buff, sep, &line);
        if (!addr) {
            continue;
        }

        char *flags = strtok_r(NULL, sep, &line);
        if (!flags || flags[0] != 'r' || flags[3] == 's') {

            //log_info("######## FIRST CRASHING IF ********************");
            //
            /*
                1. mem section cound NOT be read, without 'r' flag.
                2. read from base addr of /dev/mail module would crash.
                   i dont know how to handle it, just skip it.

                   1f5573000-1f58f7000 rw-s 1f5573000 00:0c 6287 /dev/mali0

            */
            continue;
        }
        strtok_r(NULL, sep, &line);  // offsets
        char *dev = strtok_r(NULL, sep, &line);  // dev number.
        int major = 0, minor = 0;
        if (!phrase_dev_num(dev, &major, &minor) || major == 0) {

            //log_info("######## SECOND CRASHING IF ********************");
            /*
                if dev major number equal to 0, mean the module must NOT be
                a shared or executable object loaded from disk.
                e.g:
                lookup symbol from [vdso] would crash.
                7f7b48a000-7f7b48c000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0  [vdso]
            */
            continue;
        }

        strtok_r(NULL, sep, &line);  // node

        char* filename = strtok_r(NULL, sep, &line); //module name
        if (!filename) {
            continue;
        }
        std::string module_name = filename;
        std::map<std::string, elf_module>::iterator itor = m_modules.find(module_name);
        if (itor == m_modules.end() &&
                !(in_exception_list(module_name.substr(module_name.find_last_of("/\\") + 1)))) {
            void* base_addr = NULL;
            void* end_addr = NULL;
            if (phrase_proc_base_addr(addr, &base_addr, &end_addr) && elf_module::is_elf_module(base_addr)) {
                elf_module module(reinterpret_cast<ElfW(Addr)>
                (base_addr), module_name.c_str());
                m_modules.insert(std::pair<std::string, elf_module>(module_name, module));
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fd);
    return 0;

}

return -1;

}
```

Helper functions :

```
bool elf_hooker::phrase_proc_base_addr(char* addr, void** pbase_addr, void** 
pend_addr)
{
char* split = strchr(addr, '-');
if (split != NULL) {
    if (pbase_addr != NULL) {
        *pbase_addr = (void *) strtoul(addr, NULL, 16);
    }
    if (pend_addr != NULL) {
        *pend_addr = (void *) strtoul(split + 1, NULL, 16);
    }
    return true;
}
return false;
}

bool elf_hooker::phrase_dev_num(char* devno, int *pmajor, int *pminor)
{
*pmajor = 0;
*pminor = 0;
if (devno != NULL && strlen(devno) == 5 && devno[2] == ':') {
    *pmajor = strtoul(devno + 0, NULL, 16);
    *pminor = strtoul(devno + 3, NULL, 16);
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

adb shell showing "cat /proc/self/maps/" :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is quite old, but I'll still quickly answer it for future reference.

According to [a discussion in a OWASP MSTG issue](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mastg/issues/1130#issuecomment-471774484), it seems that `/proc/self/maps` is not accessible to the application on Android 7. 
It is however still possible to read the memory mapping using the pid of the app:

```
pid_t pid = getpid();

std::ostringstream filename;
filename << "/proc/" << pid << "/maps";

FILE* fd = fopen(filename.str().c_str(), "r");
```

I am not sure which Android versions are affected besides Android 7, but at the very least, it is once again possible to read `/proc/self/maps` on Android 12.